# Is there a way to disable all connecting storage devices via usb in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, usb, security, usb-drive

I am currently trying to secure a desktop and was able to disable almost all of the connecting usb flashdrive by disabling usb ports in bios and by:

```
sudo -s
enter password
chmod 000 /media/
```

But Ive noticed that it did not block my iphones app storage (afc://.../) but I was able to block the photos (gphoto2://.../)

Now is there a way to disable root `afc://`, `mtp://` and/or if theres any other root to disable?

Answer (score 0):

Have same issue, I google it and found one solution:

```
$ chmod 700 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-mtp  # if you don't want to root also change it to 000

$ chmod 700 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-afc
```